# Multiple groupby in the same table

Tags: sql, hive, aggregate-functions, hiveql

I have 4 columns in a HIVE tables

```
Level1 String
Level2 String
Level3 String
Cnt INT
```

I want to aggregate cnt at multiple levels separately in the same table i.e.

```
@Level1
@Level1, Level2
@Level3
@level1,level2,level3
```

So the final table should have `sum(cnt)` for all combination of the levels in separate columns.

I initially considered doing it separately and then joining the tables but i am not sure how to make such a join or if its even possible.

Comment: can you show some sample input data and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is unclear what your final expected output should be like, you could make use of  `GROUPING SETS`

```
select level1,level2,level3,count(*)
 FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY level1,level2,level3  
GROUPING SETS ( (Level1), ( Level1, Level2), (Level3), (level1,level2,level3) );
```

You could also make use of functions like `GROUPING_ID,Grouping` etc along  with the output from this query to suit your final aggregation.

Refer : [**Enhanced Aggregation**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Enhanced+Aggregation%2C+Cube%2C+Grouping+and+Rollup)